# How to Hide and show HTML based on a cookie existing or not in a React App

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a React App that has a login system. When you log in, a cookie is created called "Name". The issue is that when you are logged in, the "Login" button is still showing, and when you are logged out, the "Logout" button is still showing. In other words, the Login and Logout button are always showing, no matter what state you are in. I created this code shown below.

When the website loads, there is a function named "check" that checks if a cookie called Name exists. If it does, "stuff" gets defined to show the Logout button only. otherwise, if there is not a cookie named Name, then "stuff" gets defined to show the Login button only.

When I load the website, nothing shows up.
How is it possible (if it is) to show different HTML based on a cookie?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";

export default function Grimm() {
  const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(["user"]);

    useEffect(() => {
      check()
    }, [])

  
  let stuff;
  function check() {
    if (cookies.Name) {
      let stuff = <Logout/>;
    } else if (!cookies.Name) {
      let stuff = <login/>
  }
  
function Login() {
  return (
    <button>
      Login
    </button>
    );
}

function Logout() {
  return (
    <button>
      Logout
    </button>
  );
}

    return (
      <div>
        {stuff}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

P.S. this is also a test site, The buttons dont do anything, its something for me to work off of. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use the correct hook
right now you are doing it wrong, you are not storing the value of your cookie inside the components state.
you need to do something like this:

```
  const [cookies, setCookie] = useState(useCookies(["user"]));
```

you need to somehow store the value of your cookie inside the state of your component

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I think I might have thrown you off with the title.  I meant to say based on a cookie existing or not. I used a wrong choice of words there

Comment: the thing is even if you set the cookie correclty on user's login, your component would not be aware of the change of your cookie, your component is only aware of it's state changing.

Comment: so you need to store the user's login in your state and update your cookie too.
if user loggs in, you set the loginState to true, if he loggs out, you set the loginState to false, and you update your cookie too.

Comment: it took me a while to get it working, but I was finally able to get it workin, thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

How about using Conditional Operator?

```
return (
    <div>
    {
    cookies.Name ? <Logout /> : <Login />
    }
    </div>
    )
```

The conditional operator check if a condition is true, and then run either a true or a false expression based on the condition.

By typing `cookies.Name ?` as the condition we check if the there is a `cookie.Name` and if found it returns true. The expression after the `?` is to render out the `<Logout />` component if the condition is true.

If there isn't a `cookie.Name` then the condition is false. If the condition is false then the part after `:` is what runs. Therefor we want it to render the `<Login />` component if there is no `cookie.Name`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).